# npm start not working after installation of webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have created an app in react-redux. After that I have installed babel and webpack using below link.

> https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8

Below is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
   output: {
       filename: 'build.js',
       //path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')},
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
   },
   module:{
       rules:[{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
       }]
   },
   plugins:[
       new HWP(
          {template: path.join(__dirname,'/src/index.html')}
       )
   ]
}
```

> I'm getting below error when I run the "npm start"

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /var/www/html/SFL
> webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot

✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry['main'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm trying to solve above error. Is there any other way to solve this error?

Comment: Can you share with us package.json file?

Comment: ok editing the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..
revert your changes and run `npm run eject`

this will enable webpack into your project

Answer (score 1):

Try this delete you node_modules && your package-lock.json

and run npm i again.

let me know if it works.

Comment: If there is another way or documentation to add webpack and babel into existing react-redux app then I can revert my changes and try with new..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `entry` to this (taken from `create-react-app`):

```
entry: [ require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/', require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'), path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js') ]
```

Comment: If there is another way or documentation to add webpack and babel into existing react-redux app then I can revert my changes and try with new..

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure should look like this

```
├── webpack.config.js
├── src
│   ├── index.js
```

Comment: Yes.. Structure is same.. If there is another way or documentation to add webpack and babel into existing react-redux app then I can revert my changes and try with new..

Comment: have you try cloning this repo in you local to see it's actually working or not https://github.com/SiddharthaChowdhury/bp-common/tree/master/app-react